# Make an entry in SQL query when no result is found

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that counts values for an specific kind of values:

```
SELECT

 B.BG_USER_05 as Functionality,
 count(case when bg_status= 'New' then 1 end) as 'New',
 count(case when bg_status= 'Open' then 1 end) as 'Open',
 count(case when bg_status= 'Assigned' then 1 end) as 'Assigned',
 count(case when bg_status= 'Fixed' then 1 end) as 'Fixed',
 count(case when bg_status= 'Ready to Test' then 1 end) as 'Ready_to_Test',
 count(case when bg_status= 'Reopen' then 1 end) as 'Reopen',
 count(case when bg_status= 'Closed' then 1 end) as 'Closed',
 count(case when bg_status= 'Rejected' then 1 end) as 'Rejected'

FROM
    BUG B,
    RELEASES R

WHERE
    B.BG_DETECTED_IN_REL = R.REL_ID

GROUP BY
    B.BG_USER_05
```

The query works correctly and returns something like this:

```
UAT 5   13  2   3   0
SIT 14  82  59  18  8
```

The issue is that sometimes, there are no UAT elements in the table (which is completely normal), which will make the result something like this:

```
SIT 14  82  59  18  8
```

The problem is that I NEED the fist row to be UAT information, and I need the result to be somethin like this:

```
UAT 0   0   0   0   0
SIT 14  82  59  18  8
```

I have no idea how to approach this.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using `left outer join`:

```
SELECT u.Functionality,
       count(case when bg_status= 'New' then 1 end) as "New",
       count(case when bg_status= 'Open' then 1 end) as "Open",
       count(case when bg_status= 'Assigned' then 1 end) as "Assigned",
       count(case when bg_status= 'Fixed' then 1 end) as "Fixed",
       count(case when bg_status= 'Ready to Test' then 1 end) as "Ready_to_Test",
       count(case when bg_status= 'Reopen' then 1 end) as "Reopen",
       count(case when bg_status= 'Closed' then 1 end) as "Closed",
       count(case when bg_status= 'Rejected' then 1 end) as "Rejected"
FROM (SELECT 'UAT' as functionality UNION ALL SELECT 'SIT') as u LEFT OUTER JOIN
     BUG B
     ON u.functionality = B.BG_USER_05 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     RELEASES R
     ON B.BG_DETECTED_IN_REL = R.REL_ID
GROUP BY u.functionality;
```

I also changed the query to use explicit join syntax (where the conditions are in the `on` clause).  And, the column aliases use double quotes rather than single quotes.  Single quotes should only be used for string and date constants; their use for identifiers often leads to confusion.

Comment: Had to remove double quotes from the query (I had to, as the query was written inside an Excel Cell, and inside double quotes.... terrible stuff, I know), bt it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, something like this:

```
SELECT Functionality, sum('New'), sum('Open'),sum('Assigned'),sum('Fixed'),sum('Ready_to_Test'),sum('Reopen'),sum('Closed'), sum('Rejected') 
from
(
SELECT

B.BG_USER_05 as Functionality,
count(case when bg_status= 'New' then 1 end) as 'New',
count(case when bg_status= 'Open' then 1 end) as 'Open',
count(case when bg_status= 'Assigned' then 1 end) as 'Assigned',
count(case when bg_status= 'Fixed' then 1 end) as 'Fixed',
count(case when bg_status= 'Ready to Test' then 1 end) as 'Ready_to_Test',
count(case when bg_status= 'Reopen' then 1 end) as 'Reopen',
count(case when bg_status= 'Closed' then 1 end) as 'Closed',
count(case when bg_status= 'Rejected' then 1 end) as 'Rejected'

FROM
   BUG B,
   RELEASES R

WHERE
   B.BG_DETECTED_IN_REL = R.REL_ID

GROUP BY
   B.BG_USER_05

UNION

SELECT 'UAT' AS Functionality,
0          AS 'New',
0          AS 'Open',
0          AS 'Assigned',
0          AS 'Fixed',
0          AS 'Ready_to_Test',
0          AS 'Reopen',
0          AS 'Closed',
0          AS 'Rejected'
)

group by Functionality
```